# Check what files are staged in git with rugged ruby

Tags: ruby, git, rugged

How can I can check what files are 'staged' or changed, but not staged with rugged?

Comment: https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#index-staging-area

Comment: OK I just reread your question, and what do you mean? You are looking for files that are 'staged' but not staged?

Comment: From the files that ared tracked, I want to get files that are modified, but unstaged. And also I want to get files that are staged with command git add <file>.

Answer (score 1):

I had a wee look and found the "[Rugged::Repository](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/Rugged/Repository)" documentation.

Scroll down to where you see:

```
repo.status { |file, status_data| puts "#{file} has status: #{status_data.inspect}" }
```

This might help.